# Custom Attribute not firing on break point

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

I created a custom attribute for object validation and I set a breakpoint anywhere in `TaskValidatorAttribute` class it seems it doesn't do or trigger anything. See my code below:

**Custom Attribute**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public TaskValidatorAttribute: Attribute
{
   public TaskValidatorAttribute(Type type)
   {
      if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseClass))) 
      {
          // some code for validation
      }
   }
}
```

**Base Class**

```
public abstract class BaseClass {}
```

**Inherited Class**

```
[TaskValidator(typeof(ModelTest))]
public class ModelTest : BaseClass {}
```

**Unit Test**

```
public class ModelValidationTests
{
   [Fact]
   public void ValidateModel()
   {
      var model = new ModelTest();
      model.ShouldNotBeNull();
   }
}
```

I try to run it in my unit test to trigger the custom attribute that I made but no luck.  Did I missed something?

Comment: Are you trying to create a custom validation attribute? This might be change from `public TaskValidatorAttribute: Attribute` to `public TaskValidatorAttribute: ValidationAttribute`?

Comment: Hi @tontonsevilla, yes indeed, I created my own custom validation...

Comment: Hi @tontonsevilla, it seems it doesn't trigger using the `ValidationAttribute`, hmp.. not quite sure why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create an instance of the `ModelTest` class, that doesn't mean that an instance of the attributes applied to that class is created. The attributes will only be instantiated if you explicitly get them. If fact, you don't even need an instance of the `ModelTest` class for that!

So the key here is that the attribute is not a part of the object, it's a decorator with different purpose and lifecycle.

Try with this:

```
public class ModelValidationTests
{
   [Fact]
   public void ValidateModel()
   {
      object[] attributes = typeof(ModelTest).GetCustomAttributes(true);
      attributes.ShouldNotBeNull();
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for answering but I already did using `GetCustomAttributes` to trigger it but I am not quite sure why it needs it in the first place? Is there any other way to solve the issue without calling `GetCustomAttributes`?